# CSS media query break points

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I've been working on some web lately and now I'm on part that I have to make my header and footer responsive. I've done some research of common media query breakpoints, but I can't find answer to my question. Is it bad practice to set different media queries around website? For example, my footer don't have to wrap when my header navigation has to narrow in hamburger button. So I would set media query for header on 991px, but footer wrap for example on 800px. Thanks

Comment: it's not bad practice to set media queries for different breakpoints. keep in mind there are a lot of different devices that can access to the internet and thus your website. there's no reason to make media queries with small increments though, like a media query for 350px and a media query for 365px.

Comment: @SigurdMazanti Yeah mate, thats what I was thinking. I just toggle device toolbar and set up Dimensions: Responsive and check where I have to put breakpoint for specific compontent. I think in that way i wouldn't miss any kind of device. Right?

Comment: that's fine, don't make a new media query for each element though. try to combine some of them

Comment: Thanks a lot mate for advice! apprechiate it :)